# Append possibly non-existent environment variable in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to append the value `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp` to the environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS`. The thing is, this variable may be present or not depending on Jenkins global configuration.

I'm using the EnvInject plugin and my properties file content is:

```
MAVEN_OPTS=${MAVEN_OPTS} -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp
```

All is fine, if `MAVEN_OPTS` already exists, but if it's not, the result is recursively expanded in my shell script:

```
echo "MAVEN_OPTS=$MAVEN_OPTS"
```

Console Output:

```
++ echo 'MAVEN_OPTS=${MAVEN_OPTS} -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp ...
```

How to obtain the result with `${MAVEN_OPTS}` expanded to an empty string when it doesn't exist? If possible, without creating a properties file with a shell script.

P.S. this new value must be available to all the build steps that follow the assignment.

*Upd* just exporting a variable in a shell step won't make it available in subsequent steps:

```
[basintest] $ /u01/jenkins/jenkins_shell -xe /tmp/hudson5874700358655226456.sh
+ . /tmp/hudson5874700358655226456.sh
++ export AAA=BBB
++ AAA=BBB
++ env
++ grep AAA
AAA=BBB
[basintest] $ /u01/jenkins/jenkins_shell -xe /tmp/hudson2617221440128538418.sh
+ . /tmp/hudson2617221440128538418.sh
++ env
++ grep AAA
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to check checkbox

- [v] Inject environment variables to the build process

or

- [v] Prepare an environment for the run

Now the field "Groovy Script" is visible. The script:

```
return ["MAVEN_OPTS": getBinding().hasVariable("MAVEN_OPTS") ? MAVEN_OPTS : ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Evaluated Groovy Script** to check if `MAVEN_OPTS` is defined in global configurations. Then return a map with either `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp` appended to the value or an empty value. The `key:value` of the map will be injected as an environment variable.

[image]

```
def MAVEN_OPTS = System.getenv("MAVEN_OPTS")
if (MAVEN_OPTS) {
    def map = ["MAVEN_OPTS": "${MAVEN_OPTS} -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/jenkins/jenkins/tmp"]
    return map
} else {
    def map = ["MAVEN_OPTS": ""]
    return map
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looks like it wasn't obvious that this new value must be available to all the build steps that follow the assignment.

Comment: In what version? Mine is 2.35 and the exported var is definitely not preserved.

Comment: Only today I understood that you have to check `Prepare an environment for the run` to see this option. I thought you needed some other plugin to enable Groovy steps

Comment: this works in 2.150.3: `return ["MAVEN_OPTS": getBinding().hasVariable("MAVEN_OPTS") ? MAVEN_OPTS : ""]`